# WildFly globally enable pretty print in development, but not in production

Tags: json, jackson, wildfly, pretty-print, wildfly-10

I'd like to globally enable JSON pretty-printing for my project on my dev machine, while leaving it off on production.

What approaches could I follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System property. You did not specify how do you control the pretty printing now, or how do you use it, but in general you should enable/disable it based on the presence/value of some custom defined system property (standalone mode: `/system-property=com.acme.enablePrettyprint=true`, domain mode: `/server-group=my-group/system-property=com.acme.enablePrettyprint=true`) that you read in the component that enables/disables the feature (`System.getProperty("com.acme.enablePrettyprint", "false")`).

Make it off by default and enable it explicitly on your dev environment by setting the system property in your server config.

Comment: I will have a go at this in the next days, thank you